# ConcurrentModificationException using subList?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a regular RecyclerView.

My RecyclerView has a listener interface that the Activity listens on. When an item in the RecyclerView is clicked, the "onItemClick()" event is called.

When this event is called, I need to remove the next 5 items from the RecyclerView, and add them into a `Map` (`Map<Integer, List<Object>>`). If the same item in the RecyclerView is clicked again, I want the 5 items to be re-added to the RecyclerView.

Here is what my code looks like in my Activity (note I removed all irrelevant code, like the `onCreate()` method, etc.):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyAdapter.MyAdapterListener {

    // The RecyclerView data
    private List<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();

    // The Map to keep track of all removed data
    private Map<Integer, List<Object>> removedData = new HashMap<>();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    private MyAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Item item = (Item) data.get(position);

        // Check if the Map key/value pair already exists
        if (removedData.get(item.getId()) != null) {
            // Key/value pair exists, re-add the 5 items into the
            // RecyclerView and remove the key/value pair from the Map

            List<Object> fiveItems = removedData.get(item.getId());

            // Re-add the five items to the RecyclerView
            data.addAll(position, fiveItems);

            // Remove the key/value pair from the Map
            removedData.remove(item.getId());
        } else {
            // Key/value pair doesn't exist, remove the next 5 items
            // from the RecyclerView and add it to the Map

            int start = position + 1;
            int end = position + 5;

            List<Object> fiveItems = data.subList(start, end);

            // Add the five items to the Map
            removedData.put(item.getId(), fiveItems);

            // Remove the items from the RecyclerView
            data.subList(start, end).clear();
        }

        // Notify data set changed
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

However, I get this error on the line `data.addAll(position, fiveItems)`:

```
06-FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(ArrayList.java:1028)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:136)
    at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:589)
    at com.my.package.activity.MainActivity.onItemClicked(MainActivity.java:238)
    at com.my.package.adapter.MyAdapter$ViewHolderItem.onClick(MyAdapter.java:235)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Why am I getting this error? How do I fix it?

Comment: Did you read subList docs? *The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)* in other words - you shouldn't modify it(data list) if you are using subList

Comment: What can I use other than subList in order to get the next 5 items from the list?

Answer (score 1):

In your data.addAll(position, fiveItems) method internally use   Object[] a = c.toArray() which use Iterator it = iterator();.When you will use iterator and same time if some other one change the same list then the modCount will change which cause the exception.So you need to find out that code responsible for it.

toArray()  source code from java api

```
Object[] r = new Object[size()];
        Iterator<E> it = iterator();
        for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
            if (! it.hasNext()) // fewer elements than expected
                return Arrays.copyOf(r, i);
            r[i] = it.next();
        }
        return it.hasNext() ? finishToArray(r, it) : r;
```